# How can I show the things I searched from Google Search Engine in the card layout?

Tags: javascript, css, google-api, google-custom-search, cardlayout

[image]

I created a search engine with Google search engine and added it to my project. However, I am currently stuck. I want to stylize the results in a card layout and show them side by side. How can I achieve this?

```
 HTML: 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Book Finder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div id="title">
                Book Finder
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant:wght@300&family=Fira+Code:wght@500&family=Josefin+Slab:wght@200&family=Kanit:wght@300&family=MedievalSharp&family=Mulish&family=Radio+Canada:wght@300&family=Smythe&family=Zen+Dots&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=d4f7eccee00f1434d">
        </script>
        <div class="gcse-search"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    >      .gsc-result-info {
    >         /* background-color: red; */
    >         font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;;
    >         color: blue;
    >     }
    >     
    >     .gs-title {
    >        font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    >        
    >         height: 100%;
    >         width: 100%;
    >         position: relative;
    >         transition: transform 1500ms;
    >         transform-style: preserve-3d;
    >       
    >        
    >     }
    >     
    >     .gsc-cursor-page {
    >         font-size: 1.5em;
    >         padding: 4px 8px;
    >         border: 2px solid #ccc;
    >           
    >     
    >       }
    >     
    >       .gs-image-box gs-web-image-box gs-web-image-box-portrait {
    >         height: 100%;
    >         width: 100%;
    >         position: relative;
    >         transition: transform 1500ms;
    >         transform-style: preserve-3d;
    >       }
```

My aim is to shape the outputs as I want, put them side by side and display them in the layout. But I can't do what I want.

Comment: Using Bootstrap library's card will be helpful and time efficient.

Comment: I tried this. But I can't show the results side by side. I can only change the color, I couldn't adjust their position.

Comment: Please share your view code and css. i can help you

Comment: I updated. I hope I explained my problem well. Google search engine classes are different. It is possible to see this only from the developer module. If you google search engine stlyzing, you will probably understand my problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter which way I style it. Just tell me how I can show them side by side in a card.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property in the class of the result wrapper.

```
float:left;
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: Thanks but ıt's not working...